# Back button does not show up in navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have added a show segue from table cell in one view controller to another table view embedded in a navigation controller. When I click on the cell in the first view the segue works as expected and brings up the new view. However, the "Back" button (with the title of the original view) does not appear in the navigation bar.

I searched SO and found a number of such questions asked in the past (both for Swift and Objective-C). Most of them suggest that the first view needs a title for this to work. I do have a title. I even added one programmatically, just in case. That did not help. One of the answers suggested to add an identifier to the segue; that didn't help me either.

How else can I debug this issue?

[image: xcode window][image: main window][image: detail window]

Comment: probably because u present the new view as `modal`, try `push` instead, with programatically present, do a `self.navigationController.pushViewController`. And, the new view shouldn't also embed in navigationController, it have to be the same navigationController as the parents one

Comment: why don't you put up some code here. the way how you present the second viewController

Comment: I agree with @Tj3n, since you say "brings up the new view", you're probably doing a modal segue. If you're doing it programatically then use pushViewController as Tj3n mentioned, if you're not, in your storyboard instead of picking present modally pick show

Comment: I just posted some screenshots that should show that I am not presenting modally. I wanted to avoid writing code for this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that you are pushing into a totally new `navigationController`, remove it, and make segue dirrectly into the new view `Detail` itself, they have to be in the same `navigationController` to work

Comment: I thought you embed your table (or some other view) in a navigation controller to get this automatic "Back" button feature, no?

Comment: You should only embed your parent VC into a navigation controller, not your child view, if u did, it become a totally new navigation controller and wont show the back button after push, in this case, only your tableView with the cell should be embed in the navController, not the `detail` view

Comment: That is exactly what the problem is. Thanks a ton. I somehow assumed that I needed to embed even the child views in the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Verify you are not hiding backbutton in destination controller...

Answer (score 0):

I had a `left bar button item` in storyboard removing the button, back button showed up.

Answer (score 0):

probably because u present the new view as modal, try push instead

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).