# Can not go back once I start UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm starting a new `UIViewController` with

```
let myViewController = MyViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
```

But then on my MyViewController() I do not see the arrow to go back, what I'm missing?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Back button does not show up in navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448726/back-button-does-not-show-up-in-navigation-controller)

Comment: is your navigationBar hidden?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are 2 solutions to go back.

1. You should use Navigation Controller.

   - Then, make the RootViewController, and connect other ViewController to RootViewController by Seague.
   - Then, pesent the ViewController by performSegue from the current ViewController(RootViewController).

[image]

[image]

2. You can also implement the back by NavItem.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not use init method inside MyViewController class, load  MyViewController() with storyboard identifier.